# How to link privacy policy page with the label text on Acceptance Checkbox?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, privacy-policy

In my WordPress website, I want the users to be able to view privacy policy of my website as soon they submit any form. I have used Contact Form 7 plugin and within every form (Forms are about 12 - 14 on my website) I have included an Acceptance Checkbox so that users can check it before they submit a form.

I want my privacy policy page to be linked with the text Privacy Policy of acceptance checkbox label (I agree to the Privacy Policy.) Is there any way to link  that page within [acceptance your-consent] I agree to the Privacy Policy. [/acceptance] form tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
[acceptance your-consent] I consent to your <a href="">Privacy Policy</a>. [/acceptance]
```

[1] https://contactform7.com/acceptance-checkbox/